# Hostname from file in SSH config

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a file which contains just the IP address of the server. I would like to have an SSH config which gets the pathname from that file.

For example instead of this:

```
Host insight-prod-manager-1
  User root
  Hostname 127.0.0.1
```

I would like this:

```
Host insight-prod-manager-1
  User root
  HostnameFile path/to/ip_address
```

I looked at the man pages but couldn't find anything

Comment: I don't think ssh_config supports exactly what you're looking for.  If you can generate additional files that contain "Hostname <ip address>", then you could use an Include of that file inside the Host block.  Or you could generate the entire Host block (or maybe even all Host blocks) and include them from ssh_config.  Depending on your situation, perhaps you could just get rid of the need to configure Hostname, e.g., by adding to /etc/hosts or by creating DNS records.

Answer (score 2):

ssh doesn't support this. Here are a couple of workarounds:

- use a system configuration manager like Ansible or Puppet to automatically create your ssh config from a template.
- run your own DNS server with a custom zone like "host.local" that resolves names like "this.host.local" or "that.host.local" to the IPs you choose.
- set up a local proxy such as stunnel, a script that calls netcat invoked from systemd/inetd, or other software that connects to the host you want based on the contents of a file somewhere. Then set up your ssh config with a hostname that points to the local host and port number that the proxy is listening on.

All of these solutions require some programming skills, the last is probably the least complex if you're not familiar with any of the suggested tools.